# Приложение вылетает при вводе запятой в plainText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

приложение вылетает при вводе float числа используя запятую.
С точной работает.
Например
1.5
5.8 (работать будет)

1,5
5,8 (Приложение остановлено)

````
    lateinit var bindingClass: ActivityMainNanoFiberBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        bindingClass = ActivityMainNanoFiberBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bindingClass.root)




        // Обработка нажатия на бтн

        bindingClass.button.setOnClickListener {

            val width = bindingClass.edTextWidth.text
                 // Получили данные с edText(Цвет Ширина)

            val height = bindingClass.edTextHeight.text // Получили данные с edText(Высота)

            if (width.toString() != "" && height.toString() != "") {

                val modelFilterPrice = 6970.18f   // профиль
                val jumper = 268.61f    //перемычка
                val corner = 60f    // уголок
                val handle = 60f    //ручка
                val jumpermm: Float = width.toString().toFloat()    //перемычка в мм
                val yardage: Float = width.toString().toFloat() * height.toString().toFloat()   //площадь
                val profileLength: Float = (width.toString().toFloat() + height.toString().toFloat()) * 2  //длина профиля
                val canvas: Float = yardage * modelFilterPrice   //полотно

                // Обработка
                val color_profile = bindingClass.colorFilterProfile
                val color_profile_selected =
                    color_profile.selectedItem.toString() // Получили данные со спиннера(Цвет профиля)

                val qwe: Float = if (color_profile_selected ==
                    "Коричневый внутренний" || color_profile_selected == "Белый внутренний"
                ) {
                    630.3f
                } else {
                    309.96f
                }

                val profile: Float = profileLength * qwe   //профиль из выборки (ПРИСВОЕНИЕ)
                val jumper2: Float = jumper * jumpermm   //перемычка
                val corner4: Float = corner * 4  //уголок
                val handle2: Float = handle * 2   //ручка
                val price = canvas + profile + jumper2 + corner4 + handle2



                bindingClass.result.text = price.toString() + "Руб."
                bindingClass.tvResult.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
                bindingClass.tvResult.text = "Стоимость:"
            }

            else {
                bindingClass.tvResult.text = "Заполните поля Ширина и Высота!"
                bindingClass.tvResult.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))
            }
            }

    }
}```
````

Comment: val width = bindingClass.edTextWidth.text
 val height = bindingClass.edTextHeight.text
Это проблемные переменные

Comment: поздравляю, вы открыли (для себя) [десятичный разделитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C). а в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: В сбилженом приложении, если поставить запятую, и нажать кнопку, приложение крашится, может есть возможность использовать float, как с точкой, так и с запятой?

Comment: [и прочее в том же духе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C).

Comment: @Type, а в логи вы смотрели, когда приложение падает то там много красного текста и ссылки на строку, если не сможете разобраться в чем проблема по логам, то их не помешает прикрепить к вопросу, чтобы у читающих и отвечающих было больше контекста

Answer (score -1):

Всего лишу нужно было поставить тип **numberDecimal**.
Спасибо aleksandr barakin!

Comment: Это вы научились как правильно контролы для ввода десятичных чисел настраивать. А вот что делать с падающим кодом типа`"1,55".toFloat()`?